# Clipping a polygon from a raster without georeference

Tags: qgis, raster

Is it possible to clip a polygon from a raster layer without being georeferenced? 
When I try I get this error message
 "ERROR 1: Unable to compute a transformation between pixel/line 
and georeferenced coordinates"
and am not really sure what it means. I'm speculating that it wants me to georeference the raster layer but I can't as it is a photo, not a map (not a photo of a map) and if I just georeference arbitrarily to try and placate it then the pictures warps.

Comment: If its not geospatial data, why not use some other application to cut out a part of the picture?

Comment: @BradHards - I'm doing a load of stats and other stuff using QGIS with my pictures and have ~1000 to do. I want to come up with a method that avoids jumping back and forth between applications.

Comment: got the same error message trying to clip a global land survey raster

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/163455)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/163455)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the raster may be left un-georeferenced, a vector layer can not. You need coordinates in a defined CRS for the vertices of the polygon.

What you can do:

Choose an arbitrary projected CRS (like Web mercator EPSG:3857), and set the extent of the raster with `gdal_translate -a_ullr` (see http://www.gdal.org/gdal_translate.html) exactly to the size of the raster. This prevents the raster from getting stretched. Make sure that the layer and project CRS are EPSG:3857 if it does not look as expected.

Then you can create a polygon layer in the same CRS, and use the clip function.

---

**UPDATE**

Your issue seems to be a bit tricky. Gdalwarp expects to do some kind of transforming, but fails on an identical reprojection.

This way it works for me:

```
gdal_translate -of Gtiff -a_srs EPSG:3857 -a_ullr 0 3456 4608 0 Aarhus.jpg AarhusNew.tif
gdalwarp -q -cutline clippoly.shp -tr 1.0 1.0 -of GTiff -dstnodata 0 AarhusNew.tif -overwrite  clipped.tif
```

You have to re-create the clip layer, because all coordinates are now positive (whereas negative Y values fail in your example, beeing identical to the internal pixel/line reference).

looking like this:

[image]

Comment: When I imported/ created the layers previously I have already been setting the CRS as 3857 and getting error message ERROR 1.  I'm not really sure what the gdal translate is meant to do but when I run it I get the message
 "Input file size is 4608, 3456 
Computed -srcwin 0 0 4608 -3455 from projected window. 
Error: Computed -srcwin 0 0 4608 -3455 has negative width and/or height"

Comment: I still get exactly the same error message

Comment: Can you upload a sample file via dropbox or similar?

Comment: Dunno if I've done this correctly but here is a link to the file I'm playing with: https://www.dropbox.com/s/qbsh4lsj29uqrke/practice.qgs?dl=0
For bonus points, this one has my standard error message on it: https://www.dropbox.com/s/wv6lmqbd9a4cy2p/Screenshot%202016-08-23%2019.40.55.png?dl=0

Comment: The .qgs file does not reveal everything. Adding the tif (or png) and shapefile (with shx/dbf/prj, maybe zipped) might help to reproduce the error.

Comment: I think I've put in the relevant files: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/nviwpk34hrqtj27/AACJyoxX2EZcAxKOXctFMbw4a?dl=0

Comment: See my extended answer.

Comment: I give up. I've spent ages trying to comprehend what you wrote but I just have no idea what that means. Sorry. I don't know is that a piece of code I can copy into somewhere? And if so where? Or is it a series of steps to do? My GIS knowledge just isn't up to understanding that.

Comment: These are GDAL command lines to reproject the datasource. You can run them inside the OSGEO4W shell, if you navigate to the folder where the files are. Inside QGIS, you can use `Raster -> Conversion -> Translate` and `Raster -> Projections -> Warp` to get a GUI around these commands. Select filenames and target SRS, then click on the pencil next to the bottom input box, and add the options that have not yet been set manually, then hit `OK`.

Comment: Just out of interest: Why warp and not clip? I've never heard of warp before. It certainly works (thankyou!) but wondered how I would know to use it in the future?

Comment: You are right, It should be `Raster -> Extraction -> Clipper`. With a mask layer, both use the same gdalwarp command line tool in the background. With a bounding box, clipper uses gdal_translate.